# Are Quick Actions really only available in Chatter? Can we somehow get a 'Create a Record' to display on the standard page layout?

Tags: button, quickaction, salesforce-classic

Apologies in advance, because I find quick actions and publisher actions confusing and I didn't find a clear-cut answer on forums or documentation...

We are trying to not reintroduce URL hacks, which we have previously used to create child records, which worked nicely to pre-populate fields based on the parent. However in order to be 'lightning ready' we are attempting new workarounds.

One thing that appealed to me was the 'Predefined Field Values' feature within a 'Create a Record' action.

However when setting up this up I don't see where I can put this button at the top of the page layout or the related list in classic? Are we really only limited to adding these in Chatter, because our company almost always 'hides the feed.'

Can we add 'Quick Actions' or 'Create a Record Actions' to the standard page layout?

I should note that I built the button on the Parent, to create Children and didn't see a way to build one on the Child.

[image]

[image: page layout]

Comment: So you are using `force:createRecord` in your lightning component and that you want to put the button to invoke that component on a page layout, is that correct?

Comment: No this is actually purely an admin question. I'm actually trying to utilize the Predefined Field Values' feature within a 'Create a Record' action on a standard page layout in Classic. I'm just finding it odd that my action is only shows up in the Chatter feed.

Comment: Action you have created will be available in Lightning Experience (LEX). In classic if you add to the Classic Publisher section in the layout, it will be displayed with chatter publisher. If your solution is for classic, I think your options are still limited to creating Detail Page Button (you can use `URLFOR()` function to create new record by the way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The quick action mainly introduced for Lightning Experience and mobile
>   app. Yes, you are right, in classic you are limited to adding a quick
>   action to chatter.

1. In Lightning, You can add a quick action on detail page layout by
   adding it to Salesforce Mobile and Lightning experience action.
2. You can also add a quick action to a list view of Object record. It has limitation too what kind of quick action you can add.
3. You can not add a quick action in the related list in Lightning
   Experience or mobile or classic as it is limited to button only.

> In Salesforce Classic, quick actions appear in the Chatter publisher.
>   In Lightning Experience, they appear in different areas of the user
>   interface, depending on the action’s type. In the Salesforce mobile
>   app, actions of all types appear in the action bar, the action bar’s
>   action menu, and as list-item actions.

Reference:- https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_overview.htm&type=5